# Solving $z^2-2iz+1=0$ in complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Solve: $z^2-2iz+1=0$

I did: 
$$(z-i)^2-(i)^2+1=0$$
$$(z-i)^2+2=0$$
$$((z-i)-\sqrt{2})((z-i)+\sqrt{2})$$
but that's wrong. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by rt(2) you mean the squareroot of $2$, so $\sqrt{2}$, the problem is that you have to "put the $2$ on the other side" so you nee to take root of $-2$.

Or, recall $X^2 - a^2 = (X-a)(X+a)$ and so $X^2 + a^2 = (X-ia)(X+ia)$.

Comment: oh ok thanks so much